# How do I 'Perform a sweet impact while going at a very low speed'?

Tags: burrito-bison-revenge

How do I complete the mission "Perform a sweet impact while going at a very low speed" in Burrito Bison Revenge?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Luck

Long Answer: Your best bet is to max out Propeller Hats and then try to hit a Propeller Hat just before your speed runs out. Then of course you have to get green on all three lights.

If you are severely lucky you could rocket bounce off of 2-4 floating gummies and get into the clouds just before your speed runs out.

Answer (score -1):

Catching a plane, while going really slow ans soaring into the clouds.